# When I press CTRL+Space the auto completing not working in my Ecllipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> the auto completing not working.

It doesn't show any suggestion which we see like after `objName`.*methodNames*

What can be the problem, How can I solve that?

Comment: You need to add more to your question. Define "not working". Is the list empty? If so you are probably mistyping a variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your "Keys" preferences: maybe the Content Assist" shortcut has been overridden by another command which would also use ctrl+space.

also see these links you may find your solution there:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/

http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-solve-the-ctrl-space-auto-complete-not-working-problem-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

@NilayOnAndroid dear i was also going through dis problem and i have made all the possible attempts to solve it but failed. In the last I again downloaded New eclipse Juno, this is working well enough. You dont have to install everything again just go and download Eclipse juno from [http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-parallel-application-developers/junosr1-rc3] and everything will remain the same just give new name to the workspace so that you can use your previous softwares on this Juno Eclipse. After dis you just need to download Android supporting libraries from[https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/] in  HELP>INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE then add this link andd thats it....
Enjoy android

Answer (score 0):

Configure Eclipse’s content assist, go “Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced“. Make sure “Other Java Proposals” is ticked